# WireMock for GraphQL API

Tags: java, graphql, wiremock

I am trying to Implement WireMock for a GraphQl Request API, but it is returning error 500 instead of taking stub.

Here is my code.

```
wireMockgraphQRule.stubFor(post(urlPathMatching("/graphql/graphql"))
```

Below is the error I am getting.

> API_Name: GraphQLClass API_URL: http://localhost:7777/graphql/graphql
>   APP_STATUS: Failure RESPONSE_CODE: 500

Anyone implemented Wiremock for Graphql, please share some pointers on implementing same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour]  and read the information guides in the help center [help]. Users are much more likely to help if you (1) show some research effort on your own (Google and StackOverflow searches), (2) learn what are appropriate questions for this forum, (3) show your images and (4) provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example to your specific problem.

Comment: Can you please elaborate more.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wiremock-user